# Apache Spark. UDF Column based on another column without passing it's name as argument.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

There is DataSet with column firm, I'm adding another column to this DataSet - firm_id here's example:

```
private val firms: mutable.Map[String, Integer] = ...
private val firmIdFromCode: (String => Integer) = (code: String) => firms(code)
val firm_id_by_code: UserDefinedFunction = udf(firmIdFromCode)
...
val ds = dataset.withColumn("firm_id", firm_id_by_code($"firm"))
```

Is there a way to eliminate passing `$"firm"` as argument (this column is always present in DS). 
I am searching for something for this:

```
val ds = dataset.withColumn("firm_id", firm_id_by_code)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could supply the column it will be using when you define the udf.

```
val someUdf = udf{ /*udf code*/}.apply($"colName")

// Usage in dataset
val ds = dataset.withColumn("newColName",someUdf)
```